# How to fix a CompileDylibError when using Xcode previews with UIKIT? Compiling failed: ';' statements are not allowed

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, swiftui

Using Xcode previews on a UIKIT view, shows the error below:

```
';' statements are not allowed

----------------------------------------

CompileDylibError: Failed to build ViewController.swift

Compiling failed: ';' statements are not allowed

/Users/alphabo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RESThub-cesavxofrobmqdgtjbapqzddtkca/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/RESThub/Intermediates.noindex/RESThub.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RESThub.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ViewController.2.preview-thunk.swift:76:18: error: ';' statements are not allowed
#sourceLocation();
                 ^

/Users/alphabo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RESThub-cesavxofrobmqdgtjbapqzddtkca/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/RESThub/Intermediates.noindex/RESThub.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RESThub.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ViewController.2.preview-thunk.swift:84:18: error: ';' statements are not allowed
#sourceLocation();
                 ^
```

The Xcode project compiles fine with no errors or warnings but the previews don't work.
The source code for the ViewController is below:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  RESThub
//
//  Created by Harrison on 7/25/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Harrison. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

final class RestViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var feedTableView: UITableView!

    // MARK: Variables

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // TODO: GET a list of gists
    }

    @IBAction func createNewGist(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // TODO: POST a new gist
    }

    // MARK: Utilities
    func showResultAlert(title: String, message: String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default))

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

// MARK: UITableView Delegate & DataSource
extension RestViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "feedCellID", for: indexPath)

        return cell;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

        let starAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Star") { (action, view, completion) in

            // TODO: PUT a gist star
            completion(true)
        }

        let unstarAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Unstar") { (action, view, completion) in

            // TODO: DELETE a gist star
            completion(true)
        }

        starAction.backgroundColor = .blue
        unstarAction.backgroundColor = .darkGray

        let actionConfig = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [unstarAction, starAction])
        return actionConfig
    }

}

#if DEBUG
import SwiftUI
extension RestViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> RestViewController {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        guard let viewController =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewController") as? RestViewController else {fatalError("Cannot load from storyboard")}
        return viewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: RestViewController, context: Context) {
    }
}
#endif

// MontactListControllerPreviews.swift
#if DEBUG
import SwiftUI
struct TermsViewControllerPreviews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            RestViewController()
                .navigationBarTitle("Contacts")
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

[Project On GitHub](https://github.com/byaruhaf/RESThub)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI view must be a struct, so you cannot use extension as you did, instead use the following

```swift
#if DEBUG
import SwiftUI
struct RestViewControllerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> RestViewController {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        guard let viewController =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewController") as? RestViewController else {fatalError("Cannot load from storyboard")}
        return viewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: RestViewController, context: Context) {
    }
}
#endif

// MontactListControllerPreviews.swift
#if DEBUG
import SwiftUI
struct TermsViewControllerPreviews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            RestViewControllerView()
                .navigationBarTitle("Contacts")
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

**Update:** remove ';' in TableView delegate callbacks as below. Tested with Xcode 11.4

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1 // << here !!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "feedCellID", for: indexPath)

        return cell // << here !!
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @Asperi that fixed it's working with both and struct and Class extension, strange that Xcode compiles but previews fail because of a `;`